# How do I know if I'm pulling from Docker Hub?

Tags: docker

If I do

```
docker pull somethinga/somethingb:sometag
```

how exactly do I know if I'm pulling image `somethingb:sometag` from a registry hosted at `somethinga` or if I'm pulling image `somethinga/somethingb:sometag` from docker hub?

I noticed that, currently at least, dockerhub only seems to allow docker ids that "Use 4 to 30 letters & digits only."  So `gcr.io/blah:blah` doesn't seem like it's going to get interpreted as an image from Docker Hub.

But what's the actual procedure?  Does the `docker pull` command try to use `somethinga` as the hostname and then fall back to checking Docker Hub?  Or is it the otherway around?

Is this actually specified somewhere?

Comment: I think the linked question covers it. But since I'm both the one that asked and answered it, let me know if your question is different and I can reopen.

Comment: @BMitch That pretty much covers it.  The one bit I didn’t  see in your answer is if the docker code can be considered specification—could this unexpectedly change in some subtle way in the future?

Comment: Good observation. The reference syntax hasn't been defined by OCI, so it's just been the community following Docker's lead for compatibility. That said, `distribution/distribution` was donated to the CNCF, so that implementation decision kinda went with it.